# Not able to call Sanitize method from javascript in Android 4.4 where as same is working in Android 4.1

Tags: c#, android, webview, xamarin.android, android-4.4-kitkat

Not able to call Sanitize method from javascript in Android 4.4 where as same is working in Android 4.1. we can call Sanitize method from android 4.1 like Foo.sanitize('test message') where as same is not working in 4.4. Can someone please try to resolve how to call sanitize method.
if we add [Export] & [JavascriptInterface] again its working but ideally no need to these annotations to call sanitize.

```
 using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Webkit;
using Java.Interop;
using Android.Net;

namespace WebViewJavaScriptInterface
{

[Activity (Label = "Mono WebView ScriptInterface", MainLauncher = true)]
public class JavaScriptInterfaceActivity : Activity
{
const string html = @"<html><body><p>This is a paragraph.</p><button type=""button"" onClick=""Foo.sanitize('test message')"">Click Me!</button></body></html>";

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        WebView view = FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.web);
        view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        view.SetWebChromeClient (new WebChromeClient ());
        view.AddJavascriptInterface ((Java.Lang.Object)new Foo (this), "Foo");
        view.LoadData (html, "text/html", null);
    }
}

class Foo : Java.Lang.Object, UrlQuerySanitizer.IValueSanitizer
{
    public Foo (Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    Context context;

     [Export]
     [JavascriptInterface]
    public void Bar (string  message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Foo.Bar invoked!");
        Toast.MakeText (context, "This is a Toast from C#! " + message.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show ();
    }

    public string Sanitize(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Santizie.Bar invoked!");
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please try to resolve how to call sanitize method. if we add [Export] & [JavascriptInterface] again its working but ideally no need to these annotations to call sanitize.

As said in [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript), you must add `JavascriptInterface` annotation to the method, if the targetSdkVersion is 17(Android 4.2) or higher.

> Caution: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want available to your JavaScript (the method must also be public). If you do not provide the annotation, the method is not accessible by your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher.